# SSRS output list

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am new to SSRS and I cannot find how to output stuff into the list, every tutorial is for parameters.

Currently, I have a string in the textbox which looks ugly and I would like to put it to the list so users have a dropdown button.

The string is like "value1,value2,value3,value4,...." and it is all in one textbox.
I want somehow to put values in the column, but in one cell, so that users can collapse that.

THANKS!

Comment: The testbox box with the "ugly looking string" is refered to as a parameter to filter your data set. where do you get the "value1,value2,value3,value4,...." from? Do you type it in? a lot of info is missing to guide you!

Comment: @Harry Textbox is the output value for the report, and data is being fetched by the report store procedure which produces values as I have described "value1,value2,value3,value4,...." 
It does not have anything with parameters, only that parameters influence the outcome of the store procedure.

Comment: can you show what you mean as an image?

Comment: https://freeimage.host/i/HIFVR8g @Harry

Comment: You cannot use a dropdown within the output of the report. The 'List' control is just a single column table.

Comment: @AlanSchofield is there any workaround for situations like this?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do any why. If you just want to hide the details by default then you could add these in a detailed row group, set the group to be collapsed as default and then it will only be shown if the user click the `[+]` symbol. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ma_yo6VB2xs) You need to remember that SSRS was originally designed for producing paginated "paper style" reports and not to be interactive.